# How to handle Android Market referral tracking for many packages from same vendor?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

I want to add Google Analytics referrals to multiple (dozens in fact) Android products from the same vendor. The Android Market Referral Tracking URL generator expects a single package name, say com.example.application, resulting in

> http://market.android.com/details?id=com.example.application&referrer=...

However, I do not want to handle dozens of these URLs in my app, each one differing only in package name. Do referrals also pass on to the vendor if I use a Market search URL like

> http://market.android.com/search?q=%22UNIQUE%20VENDOR%20NAME%22&referrer=...

to find all products of that vendor? In that case I would need to use only a single referral URL for all (same-priced library) products of this vendor.

Your advice is much appreciated!

P.S. I had to add a few dummy spaces in the second example URL because new users may only post one hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand. The links above you would post on Twitter, or on your website, to send people to the Market page for your app. That's why you need to put in that app's package name. Obviously you can only send people to one Market page (i.e. one app), not multiple.